# PSP34Mintable::mint() as payable function

Tags: ink, smart-contract, contracts, openbrush

I'm using PSP34 from openbrush in ink! contract and want to override `mint()` function that comes with `PSP34Mintable` trait.
Since this contract should accept payments for the `mint()` call, a `payable` is added to the message.

pseudo code

```rs
impl PSP34Mintable for MyContract {
    #[ink(message, payable)]
    fn mint(&mut self, account: AccountId, id: Id) -> Result<(), PSP34Error> {
        // ... my custom code
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

gives following compile error

```rs
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/lib.rs:4:1
  |
4 | #[openbrush::contract]
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `false`, found `true`
  |
  = note: expected struct `TraitMessagePayable<false>`
             found struct `TraitMessagePayable<true>`
  = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `openbrush::contract`
```

Is it possible to change this `mint()` to become a payable message or do I need to implement a custom trait with `mint()` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create your own fn which will be payable, and call the `_mint` function in this fn. However it would be a nice thing to have, we can look into this within OpenBrush.